# Neutrino helicity

Tags: neutrinos, helicity

Neutrinos are produced in beta decays with a given helicity. My question is wether this helicity is a constant of this movement or is it variable?

Comment: Helicity is not frame-independent, if that's what you're asking. If you run faster than the neutrino, then its helicity changes.

Comment: I think that the person means is it always a set value irrespective of direction

Comment: I mean that observed from a given rest frame, if the neutrino is produced with a given helicity, wether this helicity is constant regardless the direction to which the neutrino is heading

Comment: Yes. All neutrinos have left helicity while all antineutrinos have right helicity. As mentioned above, helicity can be reversed by outrunning a neutrino (although chirality would still remain the same). However, verifying this experimentally is not possible at this time.

Comment: I guess this is the answer, helicity is frame-independent if neutrinos have mass and therefore there is a frame where you can run faster than them. If they did not have mass, such a frame would not exist, right?
I still do not get why helicity changes when you are running faster than the neutrino (can someone give a more formal answer?). Thanks

Comment: Helicity and chirality are correlated in the relativistic limit, but uncorrelated in the particle's rest frame (if it has one). There's a nice discussion in [chapter 3 of Peskin & Schroeder](https://books.google.com/books?id=_H-oPv1raioC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting point

> Neutrinos are produced in beta decays with a given helicity.

is plain unsound. Neutrinos are produced with a given chirality, which, for massive neutrinos, is distinctly different than helicity, \https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chirality_and_helicity.

Consider a positron emission β-decay, so, effectively, the disintegration of a virtual $W^+$. A right-chiral positron is produced in the nucleus' frame, in association with a left-chiral neutrino (actually a massive  "electron neutrino", which is a "fictitious" convenience linear  superposition of three massive neutrinos, but let's not muddy the waters, for now).

This left-chiral neutrino will have a wave-function with a huge component of negative helicity, and a minuscule, $O(m_\nu/p)$ component of positive helicity, normally ignored, as it would vanish for a massless neutrino and underlies your confusion about "definite helicity production".

As the comments indicate, this  mix of helicity components is frame-dependent, as always. So, if you scooted after the neutrino and you overtook it, it would appear to be receding from you in the opposite direction: so it would now be mostly of positive helicity.

(There is, of course, no such thing as left- or right- helicity... terms  virtually invented to confuse. Use at your own risk.)

Frame dependent or not, helicity is a wonderfully useful concept, much more intuitive than chirality, and has simple  accounting rules for physical systems, which is why it is routinely used.

For more formal detail, you may [see this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/372019/66086).