# Particle Physics: Decomposition of a Helicity Spinor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, chirality, helicity

I would have a general question: If we consider the decay of the $W^{-}$ boson into $l^{-}\nu_{\bar{l}}$, how can we calculate the polarization of the $l^{-}$?For example, Mark Thomson has on page 299, Eq. (11.17), the following decomposition of a right-handed helicity spinor $u_{\uparrow}$:

$$u_{\uparrow} = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \frac{p}{E + m}\right)u_{\text{R}} + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - \frac{p}{E + m}\right)u_{\text{L}} \qquad [1], $$
where $u_{\text{L}}$ and $u_{\text{R}}$ denote chiral states.

**Question:**

Is there a similar decomposition for a left-handed helicity spinor $u_{\downarrow}$ as in Eq. [1]? I coulnd't find it in the Thomson.

**EDIT:**
Following Cosmas Zachos' comment, here is where I am stuck on proving [1] on my own. I think I might manage to prove for myself a representation for $u_{\downarrow}$ once I understand [1]. So: One line before Eq. (6.38) in Thomson, he has the following Eq.: $$u_{\uparrow}\left( p, \theta, \phi \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \kappa\right)N\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi} \\ \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi}\end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\kappa\right)N\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi} \\ -\cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ -\sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi} \end{pmatrix}}_{\left(\star\right)}\qquad [2],$$ and then Eq. (6.38) (he also wrote somewhere that $s \equiv \sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $c\equiv \cos\frac{\theta}{2}$):

$$u_{\uparrow}\left( p, \theta, \phi \right) \propto \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\kappa\right)u_{\text{R}} + \frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\kappa\right)u_{\text{L}}.$$

I do not understand how $\left( \star \right)$ is supposed to be proportional to $u_{\text{L}}$. According to Thomson, "the above spinors all can be multiplied by an overall complex phase with no change in any physical predictions", page 108. According to Eq. (6.32), $$u_L = N\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \cos\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \\ -\cos\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\varphi} \end{pmatrix}}_{\left(\star\star\right)}.$$

Comparing $\left(\star\right)$ to $\left( \star\star\right)$ for the *first component* for now, and taking into account that we are allowed to habe a global phase factor of $e^{i\xi}$, I get:

$$e^{i\xi} \cdot \cos\frac{\theta}{2} = -\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$$

For me, this Equation is never satisfied, regardless of what I choose for $e^{i\xi}$ ...

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to exactly show where I am failing to prove $[1]$, because I was stumbling upon this when trying to derive a decomposition of $u_{\downarrow}$ for myself.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371983/spin-up-with-indefinite-helicity).

Comment: Let me give it a try tomorrow then. :)

Comment: You might have a point: there is a break in conventions between (6.32) and (6.38)! Have not looked into it, but he might be switching Dirac matrix to Weyl conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a particle moving in the $\hat z$ direction, for simplicity. Define $\kappa= p/(E+m)$ and note it collapses to 1 for *m* =0. In this frame,
$$
u_ \uparrow  =\sqrt{E+m} \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  \kappa\\  0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad u_ \downarrow =\sqrt{E+m}  \begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\  0\\ -\kappa \end{pmatrix}.\tag{4.65}
$$

Up to normalizations, the eigenstates of
$$
\gamma_5 = \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\!\!1 \\ 1\!\!1 &0  \end{pmatrix}
$$
have  eigenvalues $\pm 1$, respectively. We can resolve the identity $I=P_R+P_L$,
$$
P_R= \frac{1}{2}  \begin{pmatrix} 1\!\!1 & 1\!\!1 \\ 1\!\!1 &1\!\!1  \end{pmatrix} \qquad P_L= \frac{1}{2}  \begin{pmatrix} 1\!\!1 & -1\!\!1 \\- 1\!\!1 &1\!\!1  \tag{6.34}\end{pmatrix} 
$$
so that the *R,L* projections of the above helicity eigenstates are
$$
u_ \uparrow  =P_R u_ \uparrow  +P_L u_ \uparrow  \propto   \left ( \tfrac{1+\kappa}{2}\right ) \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  1\\  0\end{pmatrix}+   \left ( \tfrac{1-\kappa}{2}\right ) \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  -1\\  0\end{pmatrix}  \tag{6.38}$$
and finally
$$   u_ \downarrow =  P_R u_ \downarrow  +P_L u_ \downarrow          \propto  
\left ( \tfrac{1-\kappa}{2}\right ) \begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\  0\\  1\end{pmatrix}+   \left ( \tfrac{1+\kappa}{2}\right ) \begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\  0\\  -1\end{pmatrix} , 
$$
your resolution of the negative helicity spinor sought. Note its right and left chiral components are *different than those of the above positive helicity given*, even though they have the same eigenvalues, (and mismatched with your text's (6.32).... Probably sloppy notation).

Note that at $\kappa\to 1$, $u_\uparrow$ collapses to its right chiral projection, and  $u_\downarrow$ to *its own (different)* left-chiral projection; which is why negative helicity is improperly/confusingly sometimes called "left", and positive helicity is misidentified as "right", to remind you of its connection to chirality seen here.

Apologies I failed imagining your text might lack consistent notation.

Comment: Hi Cosmas, I see what you mean with your last sentence! I thought I must be missing sth, but I think you're right that there is an inconsistency in the text. But I like the following argument of yours most: In the ultra-relativistic limit, i. e. $\kappa \rightarrow 1$, we know that $u_{\downarrow}$ has to collapse to $u_{\text{L}}$ and thus we could already infer from that that it is has to be $u_{\downarrow} \propto \frac{1-\kappa}{2}u_{\text{R}} + \frac{1+\kappa}{2}u_{\text{L}}$. :)

Comment: I reversed your edit, as it is unsound! You already used $u_R,u_L$ for the positive helicity chiral projections above. That's why I wrote the 4-spinors explicitly.