# How is the chirality for the weak interaction conserved for non-relativistic neutrinos?

Tags: neutrinos, weak-interaction, chirality, helicity

In [this article](https://icasu.illinois.edu/news/baym_peng), one can read that the neutrinos in the [cosmic neutrino background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_neutrino_background) have a speed of about 1/50 of the speed of light, which is clearly non-relativistic.

From the viewpoint of, say, cosmic rays emerging from the sun, these slow neutrinos can change helicity. A left-handed neutrino then changes into a right-handed one.

Now, the weak interaction affects only left-handed particles and right-handed anti-particles. Does this mean that a left-handed neutrino, as seen from an observer at rest wrt co-moving coordinates, participating in a weak process, cannot participate in the same process, as seen from the frame in which high-energy cosmic rays are at rest and from which the neutrino seems right-handed? How is the chirality of the weak interaction conserved? Are non-relativistic neutrinos behaving like, say, electrons, which can have both right-handed and left-handed versions but still behave chirally?

Comment: I suspect you are confusing _helicity_ with _chirality_.

Comment: Left handed means left chiral, not with negative helicity. Are you firm on that?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, I'm aware of that. So a negative and positive helicity can both be connected to a negative and positive helicity? A left-handed neutrino stays a left-handed neutrino for ever, even when it changes chirality?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Did electrons initially have a fixed chirality too? Like the neutrinos?

Comment: Electors of both chiralities can be equally created by photons.

Comment: Helicity is frame dependent, so a suitable boost can flip it. Chirality flips automatically by dint of the mass that we now know neutrinos have. Read up.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But a slow neutrino with right chirality is still a left-handed neutrino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unclear what you are asking, but here is the [connection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609769/66086) of *slow* fermions' helicity and chirality. From (6.38), for ultra relativistic fermions, $\kappa= \frac{p}{m+E}$ goes to 1, so positive helicity ones are almost pure right-chiral, and negative helicity ones are almost pure left-chiral.

Not your case. For speed *v* ~1/50, you have $\kappa\approx 0.01$, so, by contrast,  positive helicity  fermions are almost equal parts   right-chiral and left-chiral, and similarly for negative helicity.

This holds for both electrons and Dirac neutrinos, of the same speed.

> From the viewpoint of, say, cosmic rays emerging from the sun, these slow neutrinos can change helicity. A left-handed neutrino then changes into a right-handed one.

No, really slow neutrinos produced by weak interactions change chirality, as per above.  In their frame, only about half will interact weakly.

> Are non-relativistic neutrinos behaving like, say, electrons, which can have both right-handed and left-handed versions but still behave chirally?

Indeed, *slow* Dirac neutrinos and electrons share in that feature: about half of them are liable to interact weakly in that frame. However, note there is at least a ratio of a million between electron and neutrino masses, so you must scale them appropriately. Electrons here are a mental crutch...

PS. Solar neutrinos, however, are ultrarelativistic, since their energy is ~ 300keV...