# Plane waves solutions for Dirac equation in terms of eigenstates of helicity

Tags: momentum, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, plane-wave

Suppose $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2}$ and $\sigma_{3}$ are the Pauli matrices. Given a momentum ${\bf{p}}$, we define the helicity operator:
$$ h = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} {\bf{\sigma}}\cdot {\bf{\hat{p}}} & 0 \\ 0 & {\bf{\sigma}}\cdot {\bf{\hat{p}}} \end{pmatrix} $$
where $\sigma \cdot {\bf{\hat{p}}} = \sum_{\mu=0}^{3}\sigma^{\mu}\frac{p_{\mu}}{|{\bf{p}}|}$. Let $|\pm \rangle$ be the eigenvectors of $\sigma \cdot {\bf{\hat{p}}}$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. Consider the following plane waves:
$$\psi_{+} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i(-Et+{\bf{p}}\cdot {\bf{x}})}\binom{e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}}|+\rangle}{e^{\frac{\theta}{2}}|+\rangle} \quad \mbox{and} \quad \psi_{-} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i(Et-{\bf{p}}\cdot{\bf{x}})}\binom{e^{\frac{\theta}{2}}|-\rangle}{e^{-\frac{\theta}{2}}|-\rangle}$$
Then $\psi_{+}$ is an eigenstate of $h$ with eigenvalue $1/2$ while $\psi_{-}$ is an eigenstate of $h$ with eigenvalue $-1/2$. Here, $\theta$ is a known parameter.

**Question:** Shouldn't $\psi_{\pm}$ be solutions of the Dirac equation $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi = 0$? They seem not to since, according to my calculations:
$$i\gamma^{0}\partial_{0}\psi_{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} E ^{i(-Et+{\bf{p}}\cdot{\bf{x}})}\binom{e^{\pm \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}{e^{\mp \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}$$
and, analogously:
$$i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi_{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|{\bf{p}}|e^{i(-Et+{\bf{p}}\cdot{\bf{x}})}\binom{e^{\pm \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}{-e^{\mp \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}$$
while the last term of the equation reads:
$$m \psi_{\pm} = m \binom{e^{\mp \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}{e^{\pm \frac{\theta}{2}}|\pm\rangle}$$
and the sum is clearly nonzero. To do such calculations I used the Weyl representation of the Dirac matrices:
$$\gamma^{0} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I \\ I & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \mbox{and}\quad \gamma^{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{\mu} \\ -\sigma^{\mu} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't the plane wave solutions above given in terms of eigenstates of $h$ be solutions to the Dirac equation? Moreover, should it depend on the particular representation of the gamma matrices?

Comment: You do know that helicity coincides with chirality only in the massless limit? And that the mass term connects the two chiralities? Why should the helicity operator you wrote *not* depend on the representation of γ s?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371983/spin-up-with-indefinite-helicity).

Comment: @Cosmas I am new to this subject. Could you elaborate a little more please? For instance, does your comment imply that the plane waves mentioned in my post do not satisfy Dirac's equation?

Comment: I think a mainstream text like Peskin & Schroeder would help you. Expanding solutions in helicity eigenstates is a bit unconventional. I really don't want to go into your formalism.

Comment: @Cosmas, this das taken from a book. The idea was actually to use these plane waves together with the ones associated with negative energies and show by using the superposition principle that their fourier transform is a general solution for Dirac's equation. The final expression displayed in the usual expression found in texts like peskin&Schroeder.

Comment: This is why I thought these should satisfy Dirac's equation.

Comment: I agree a positive helicity state may be a solution of Dirac's equation, but I am reluctant to get enmeshed in basis changes...