# What is the physical meaning of a pseudo-vector potential in a Dirac equation?

Tags: potential, dirac-equation

Consider a Dirac action with a pseudo-vector potential:

$$S = \overline{\psi}(\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu + i\gamma_5 A_\mu) + m_e)\psi$$

i.e. exactly like a Dirac equation with an electromegnetic potential except of the matrix $\gamma_5$.

$\tfrac{1}{2}(1\pm \gamma_5)$ are projetion operators to left/right chiral states of the electron. Basically $\gamma_5$ would give the potential a sign change depending on the chirality of the electron compared to a normal vector potential.

We might imagine that $A_\mu$ is some spherical potential, for the sake of argument.

As far as I can tell, this potential would accelerate left-handed particles towards it and accelerate right-handed particles away from it. And not depend on charge.

But then an electron nearly at rest would be a mix of left and right handed so shouldn't be affected at all (on average). Which is strange.

Is this correct? Precisely, what effect would this have on left/right handed electron/positrons?

(One might assume the electrons are moving at speeds in which a classical approximation is appropriate).

Edit: Might it be like the field of a magnetic monopole? (Just a guess.)

Comment: 1. How are you talking about "acceleration" of the particles here? Either you are in a classical theory, where $\psi$ is just a field and not anything with "particles", or you are in a quantum theory where you need to do the analog of [this computation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142172/50583) for your theory to claim anything about the classical force law this Lagrangian implies. 2. I don't see how you conclude from the electron being "a mix of left and right" that it "shouldn't be affected at all". A massive fermion is *not* necessarily an equal mixture.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I suppose take the classical approximation. On your second point, an electron with average speed 0 would have 50-50 chance of being detected left/right chirality would it not? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, I've never seen a theory like that, but in pseudoscalar Yukawa theory there is indeed a similar effect. One finds that the force between the fermions is a spin-spin interaction, roughly corresponding with what you say about chirality.

Comment: Yes, I'd imagine it would be equivalent to having two massless $Z^0$ bosons acting on left and right chiralities respectively.

Comment: @knzhou Indeed, the $h_1$(1170)  is an isosinglet axial vector hadron coupling just like that, to nucleons, strongly. Unlike the pion, the coupling  links left-handers to left-handers and right-handers to right-handers, like the photon, but with a relative minus sign. In a scattering experiment, this difference should be visible.

Comment: A fixed  mass term breaks the axial symmetry, but you get such a theory for a Weyl superconductor. The  (Majorana) mass term is then $me^{i\gamma_5 \theta}$ where $\theta$ is the phase of the superconducting order parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Dirac equation for an electron 
$$S = \overline{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu -eA_\mu) - m_e)\psi$$

Note, by replacing

$$-e \rightarrow +\gamma_5$$

you have removed the coupling of the field $A_\mu$ with particle $m_e$.

Hence, there is no charge current.

Also note, the projection operator for the electron only works when the energy of the particle is large compared to its rest mass.